# Redirect from Login form based on user type using Vb.net

Tags: vb.net, ms-access, authentication

Assume that i have a login table that stores **3** attributes:

1. USERNAME
2. PASSWORD
3. USERTYPE

*Note that i am using Access Database*

In my **login.vb** form, there is 2 **textboxes** for the user to enter their username and password. And one **Login** button to validate the login.

My question is how to redirect the windows form based on userType.
Below is my codes for **login.vb**.

```
Private Sub btn_login_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles btn_login.Click

        Dim mysql As String = "SELECT COUNT(*) AS NUM_MATCHES FROM TABLE WHERE USERNAME='" & username.Text & "' and PASSWORD ='" & password.Text & "'"

        Dim mydatatable As New DataTable

        Dim myreader As New OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter(mysql, myconnection)

        myreader.Fill(mydatatable)

        Dim num_matches As String = mydatatable.Rows(0).Item("NUM_MATCHES")


        If num_matches = 1 Then
            If userType = "CUSTOMER" Then
                username = username.Text
                form_customer.Show()
                Me.Hide()
            ElseIf userType = "STAFF" Then
                form_staff.Show()
                Me.Hide()
            End If
        Else

            txt_username.Text = ""
            txt_password.Text = ""
            MsgBox("Incorrect Username or Password")

        End If
    End Sub
```

I have set `userType` as `Public userType As String` in the module so that the whole application can access. But when i debug the application, there is no error and when i click the login button, nothing happened.

Comment: First point... at what point are you assigning userType? I can't see any code doing this. You also need to look at paramatising your sql query as in its present form its subject to Sql Injection.

Comment: @Mych i have assigned `userType = "USERTYPE"` and change the select statement by adding `USERTYPE` but still i cant redirect the page.

Comment: As mentioned below you do not need to select a count. There should be only one record for each user. So do a select * From .... (or specify the columns you need). If a record is found then assign the userType. If no record is found then the user either does not exist or they entered their username/password incorrectly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I sort of wonder why you are counting matches in your select statement but then checking for the number of matches by looking at how many rows there are in the datatable.

The way your logic is set up, as long as the user name and password are found, you have a match. Therefore the code in the if clause is executed. As others have noted, you are not assigning anything to userType here. You can prove to yourself that this is the problem by adding an ELSE clause to the code like this:

```
    If num_matches = 1 Then
        If userType = "CUSTOMER" Then
            username = username.Text
            form_customer.Show()
            Me.Hide()
        ElseIf userType = "STAFF" Then
            form_staff.Show()
            Me.Hide()
        Else
            MsgBox("Incorrect user type.")
        End If
    Else

        txt_username.Text = ""
        txt_password.Text = ""
        MsgBox("Incorrect Username or Password")

    End If
```

If I were writing this code, I would change the SQL statement to select the userType based on user name and password. You don't need to use count(*) then and can simply test the number of rows in the datatable and act accordingly.

By the way, if it is at all possible that the same username/password combination could be included in the table twice with different user types, then your test should be `If num_matches >= 1 Then` instead of `If num_matches = 1 Then` as well because in the situation where there is more than one match, execution will jump to the Else portion of the statement with the message "Incorrect Username or Password."

Answer (score 1):

There is one possible case where the code posted will not throw an error but will not open a form or display a message box either: when num_matches is 1 but userType is neither "CUSTOMER" nor "STAFF".

As pointed out in the comments, your code does not assign a value to userType. I'm assuming that it needs to do so here. I don't use MS Access myself, but I do use MySQL, and your current query is only returning the count of matches, not any other column value such as USERTYPE. You need to modify your query or add a second one to get information into your VB userType variable. Perhaps this will work:

```
Dim mysql As String = "SELECT COUNT(*) AS NUM_MATCHES, USERTYPE..."
...
userType = mydatatable.Rows(0).Item("USERTYPE")
```

That's just a guess on my part, since I use MySql.Data.MySqlClient classes for queries, but you should still get the idea.

Answer (score 1):

You really should read all the answers.... Irene has basically given you all you needed... here is a rewrite of your code.

```
Private Sub btn_login_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles btn_login.Click

    Dim mysql As String = "SELECT * FROM TABLE WHERE USERNAME='" & username.Text & "' and PASSWORD ='" & password.Text & "'"

    Dim mydatatable As New DataTable

    Dim myreader As New OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter(mysql, myconnection)

    myreader.Fill(mydatatable)

    If mydatatable.Rows.Count = 1 Then
        'we have a row
        'assign userType
        userType = mydatatable.Rows(0).Item("USERTYPE")
        If userType = "CUSTOMER" Then
            username = username.Text
            form_customer.Show()
            Me.Hide()
        ElseIf userType = "STAFF" Then
            form_staff.Show()
            Me.Hide()
        End If
    Else

        txt_username.Text = ""
        txt_password.Text = ""
        MsgBox("Incorrect Username or Password")

    End If
End Sub
```

Note that the above code does not address the issue of sql injection.